# App allocation large memory when it loads up

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-memory

In my android application I found this message in the logs when the app starts up.

```
Grow heap (frag case) to 13.781MB for 3271696-byte allocation
```

This happens soon after `setContentView()` is called and even before other part of the app gets executed.

Why does setting a content view take this much memory?

I am not sure what this means. Can some on explain please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy answer. How large is the content view? Have you ever used the Eclipse MAT? Also, how large is the screen? Is there an ImageView loading a large image? That's about the size of a *1000x1000 image.

- Note: miscalculated it earlier.

Comment: My Images are not large its just 450kb. I just have an imageview and a webview in the loading screen.

Comment: It was with my image. I removed the image and its no more showing any memory allocation. I have to show a splash screen so what would be the best wat to go forward?

Comment: There's several approaches. For example, what's the res of the device you are working on? You can restrict the resolution of the image to certain devices and make drawables accordingly. The higher res devices will have more RAM. Other approaches include chopping up the image into tiles, which may or may not work.

Answer (score 1):

setContentView(int res)  infilates the layout and adds all top level views you have.

probably images, and other complex views loads your memory this much. consider resizing your images in drawable folder.

Comment: My Images are not large its just 450kb. I just have an imageview and a webview in the loading screen.

Comment: İf you provide some code i may speak more acurate in this case. Many things can causethis.

Comment: Is that 450k before or after compression (jpeg/gif/png)? A 450k .jpeg uncompressed can be several megs after uncompression. Images tend to be uncompressed into RAM when they are displayed. I also agree with A.Ercan's statement. A bunch of 450k images can really explode the RAM usage

Comment: @ Ercan : I dont know how to provide some code. This is the first line executed in MainActivity inside onCreate method.

Comment: @JoePlante Should be before de compression. I checked the file size using explorer. But thats a standard image which is used as a splash screen.